# Exibir resultado do produto de duas variáveis com pontos ao invés de vírgula (c#)

Tags: c#

Estou resolvendo um exercício em que é necessário declarar o número de um funcionário, quantas horas ele trabalha e quanto ele recebe por hora, em seguida o sistema deve exibir o número deste funcionário e o seu salário, o problema é que o resultado deve ser exibido com pontos ao invés de vírgula nas casa decimais, meu código até o momento é este:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

class URI
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int numeroFunc, horasTrabalhadas;
        decimal valorHora;

        numeroFunc = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        horasTrabalhadas = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        valorHora = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        Console.WriteLine("NUMBER = " + numeroFunc);
        Console.WriteLine("SALARY = U$ " + (horasTrabalhadas * valorHora));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Sei que poderia resolver o problema criando uma variável salario para receber o valor de horasTrabalhadas * valorHora e utilizar o comando         `Console.WriteLine("SALARY = U$ " + salario.ToString("F2", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));` para exibir a mensagem com pontos, porém o exercício pede que não sejam criadas outras variáveis além das que foram solicitadas.

Comment: Na conversão da leitura, seu código pode gerar uma exceção. Utilize o TryParce ao invés de Parse.

int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out numeroFunc);

Answer (score 1):

Assim como não necessitou de usar uma outra variável para usar o resultado de `(horasTrabalhadas * valorHora)` no método `Console.WriteLine()`, também não necessita dela para poder usar o método `ToString()`.

Faça assim:

```
Console.WriteLine("SALARY = U$ " + (horasTrabalhadas * valorHora).ToString("F2", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

Qualquer [expressão](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expressions) resulta num valor(o seu resultado).
Todo o valor tem um tipo associado. Mesmo que a expressão não tenha sido atribuída a uma variável é possível usar os métodos desse tipo, directamente na expressão.